# Java .hasNextInt() mismatch exception

Tags: java

I have a .txt file that is formatted as follows

```
The Shawshank Redemption 
100 
19.95 
DVD
```

There are many more lines, but I'm trying to store these values into four different ArrayLists. The problem is a get the error java.util.InputMismatchException. Here is my code:

```
while(list.hasNext() && !list.nextLine().equals("")){
                titleList.add(list.nextLine());
                quantityList.add(list.nextInt());       
                priceList.add(list.nextDouble());
                typeList.add(list.nextLine());          
            }
```

The program crashes at quantityList.add(list.nextInt()); telling me that the next line is not and int, giving me that error. It will read it though if I use nextLine(). Any tips anyone can give me would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Do some debugging yourself! Find out which movie from your list/which line of the file your program gets stuck on.

Comment: Why are you putting these into four separate lists? Wouldn't it be nicer to have an object to represent each movie?

Comment: I've done plenty. It get's stuck on the '100' it won't read it as an Integer. I really can't figure out what's wrong I've been searching for about an hour for a solution.

Comment: I'm putting them into separate lists because I need to do calculations with price and quantity. It's necessary I promise

Answer (score 2):

You have already read the first line in your while statement: -

```
while(list.hasNext() && !list.nextLine().equals(""))
```

And then when you again call `nextLine` first time, you are actually reading the integer (100), using `list.nextLine` and that is why you get that exception. Because you are probably now storing a `String` in an `Integer List`. Just remove that 2nd test from `while`.

2nd problem is that, you have checked `list.hasNext()` just once, and then you are reading `4 inputs`. That may again throw you exception, if you go out of input. So, you also need to take care of that.

And another issue, which you will get is due to the usage of `list.nextInt()` and `list.nextDouble()`. Remember that, those methods read the input till the `newline` character at the end. So, the newline character left after reading will be read by the following invocation of `method` reading input, if not consumed. So, you also need to add an empty `list.next()` call after both of those methods, to consume the `newline`, so that `newline` is not read by `list.nextDouble()` used after `list.nextInt()`, else you will keep on getting exception.

---

Apart from those problems, I would suggest you to create a `Class` storing those attributes, and the have a `List` of objects of that class, rather than having 4 different lists.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do this unfortunately I'm confined to the perimeters of this project set by my teacher. They want it to be done this way. The list is about 40 lines long, all basically repeats of this format. I still get the error when removing the first nextLine. The program just does not believe that 100 is an integer I don't know how to fix it. It tells me it's reading 100.

Comment: Debugging tells me it's storing the first line correctly as Shawshank Redemption

Comment: @user2008914.. After you read `list.nextInt()`, add an empty call to `list.next()`, to read the newline, that is left over by `nextInt()`. Scanner#nextInt` does not read the newline at the end.

Comment: @user2008914.. This is a dirty way, but for now, you can put an empty `list.next()` after each line in your while. i.e, after `list.nextLine`, `list.nextInt`, and so on.

Comment: @user2008914.. But note that, this may fail badly, if you don't have those 4 sets of values for each record.

Comment: I do have that data for each movie, in the same order and format. I'm still getting the type mismatch error after all this. I can't begin to understand what's wrong here, this usually works for me.

Comment: It's telling me that it's trying to read 'The' in this situation. When I put the list.next() after the first nextLine it tries to read 19.95 skipping 100 entirely

Comment: Code is the same as before except I took out the second condition in the while, and added list.next()

Comment: @user2008914. Ah! sorry. Don't put extra `list.next()` after `list.nextLine()`, but only after `list.nextInt()` and `list.nextDouble()`.

Comment: I tried that but for the oddest reason the nextInt() command reads "The" from the file. The nextLine command should grab the whole first line then go to the next line of 100, I don't understand what's causing this to happen.

Comment: @user2008914.. Are you by any chance having some other line (May be an EMPTY line) before the `The Shawshank Redemption` line?

Comment: Nothing at all. The first line of the document is  'The Shawshank Redemption' second line is 100. very frustrating

Comment: Well, can't tell much now from the current code. May be you are doing something strange somewhere else.

Comment: Basically it goes. add.nextLine; this works, and adds the Shawshank.
then the next line where I do add.nextInt attempts to add just the word "The" it seems to be coming out of nowhere!

Comment: What it's doing is skipping the next 3 lines and going straight to the next movie!! Why could this be?!

Comment: @user2008914 Why don't you read the file line by line and the parse them accordingly.

Comment: @user2008914.. Well, I can't think of any issue here right now. May be because I need to sleep. Probably, I would take a look into this tomorrow.

Comment: I got it to work. I honestly have no idea what even changed. Thanks for all the help people. It's one of those things that literally fixed itself magically I don't even know.

Comment: @user2008914.. Oh! It's fine then. :)

Comment: This discussion is growing too long and hard to follow. However it contains good information which should be integrated into the the question or an answer. Please do that and if needed, continue the discussion in the chat!